# Shift Image on Click (somewhat similar to google maps)

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml

I am looking for some code that will allow me to manipulate a floor plan similar to that at

[whitehouse.gov](http://www.whitehouse.gov/about/inside-white-house/interactive-tour)

I have a site that I'm coding that would like to implement similar functionality for their own floor plan. Can this be accomplished through CSS or jQuery?

The idea would be to have links that, when clicked, will move the image around accordingly. If someone knows of some existing code that I can leverage or a tutorial, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) should do what you need...

The basic idea is that your image sits inside a div which has its overflow set to hidden (with a defined width and height), and you scroll to a set of co-ordinates when clicking on certain items.